# Boost Locale format

Tags: c++, boost, format

Can [the boost locale format facility](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/locale/doc/html/localized_text_formatting.html) format arguments by the order they follow?

```
format("Today {1} I would meet {2} at home") % time(0) % name
```

I would like something like this

```
format("Today {0} I would meet {0} at home") % time(0) % name
```

which produces the same result as the example above.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like it. However, you can get there.

I used to think that Boost Locale used Boost Format directly, but apparently they add some things:

```
std::cout << boost::locale::format("writing %s,  x=%s : %d-th step \n") % "toto" % 40.23 % 50; 
std::cout << boost::format("writing %s,  x=%s : %d-th step \n") % "toto" % 40.23 % 50;
```

Prints:

```
writing %s,  x=%s : %d-th step 
writing toto,  x=40.23 : 50-th step
```

So, if you want this, you should mix Boost Locale substitutions and Boost Format formatting:

### Before:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d285fa7a83bbadc)</kbd>** with positional parameters:

```
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/locale.hpp>
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{ 
    boost::locale::generator gen;
    gen.add_messages_domain("messages");
    gen.add_messages_path(".");

    for(auto loc_id : { "de_DE", "en_US", "nl_NL", "nl_BE", "fr_FR", "ru_RU" })
    {
        namespace as = boost::locale::as;
        using boost::locale::translate;
        using boost::locale::format;

        auto loc = gen.generate(std::string(loc_id) + ".UTF-8");
        std::cout.imbue(loc);
        std::cout << "---------------------------\n";

        boost::locale::date_time start_date(loc);
        start_date += boost::locale::period::day(3);
        boost::locale::date_time aug(boost::locale::period::august(), loc);

        std::cout << format(translate("{1}: Task runs every {2,ordinal} week from this {3,ftime='%A'} ({3,date})\n")) % loc_id % 3 % start_date;

        std::cout << format(translate("First period ({1}) bill is {2}\n")) 
                        % (format("{1,ftime='%B'}") % aug)
                        % (format("{1,currency}") % 42);
    }
}
```

### After

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/45e6eeaed234ff1f)</kbd>** with sprintf non-reordering parameters:

```
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>
#include <boost/locale.hpp>
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{ 
    boost::locale::generator gen;
    gen.add_messages_domain("messages");
    gen.add_messages_path(".");

    for(auto loc_id : { "de_DE", "en_US", "nl_NL", "nl_BE", "fr_FR", "ru_RU" })
    {
        namespace as = boost::locale::as;
        using boost::locale::translate;
        using boost::locale::format;

        auto loc = gen.generate(std::string(loc_id) + ".UTF-8");
        std::cout.imbue(loc);
        std::cout << "---------------------------\n";

        boost::locale::date_time start_date(loc);
        start_date += boost::locale::period::day(3);
        boost::locale::date_time aug(boost::locale::period::august(), loc);

        std::cout << boost::format(translate("%s: Task runs every %s week from this %s (%s)\n").str(loc), loc) 
                        % loc_id
                        % (boost::locale::format("{1,ordinal}") % 3)
                        % (boost::locale::format("{1,ftime='%A'}") % start_date)
                        % (boost::locale::format("{1,date}") % start_date)
                        ;

        std::cout << boost::format(translate("First period (%s) bill is %s\n").str(loc), loc) 
                        % (format("{1,ftime='%B'}") % aug)
                        % (format("{1,currency}") % 42);
    }
}
```

### Caveats

Note that there are a number of subtler points to keep in mind when mixing Boost Format with `boost::locale::format` like this (to do with exact order of application of stream manipulation and the need to pass `loc` to each call to `boost::format`). It took me some ~10 minutes to figure out just the incantation that would work for this answer.

Note also, that this example is a splendid example of why you'd want positional arguments. The word and sentence ordering might depend on the localized language.

Comment: Full demo added with Boost Locale and gettext support, [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1598fde97f02b8e1). Also added [Caveats] section at the end.

Comment: Still [27 minutes later](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27219319/revisions) the "after" example is even closer to the "before" example: [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/936da8e12bf33915)